# Can not use the Eclipse Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am beginner in writing a basic Android application.

When I try to start android SDK manager, it starts but the problem is that none of the buttons work. You can click but you don't get any to respond .

This is my environment variable :

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\;
```

i installed :

- Android sdk  installer_r20.0.3-windows.exe (windows 7 ,32 bit)
- eclipse-jee-juno-win32
- jdk-7u6-windows-i586.exe

i just tried and tried 
remove,reinstall and install 
but nothing happened 
it take 7 days  ,i really need some help

Comment: For starters, switch to jdk6.